# What is the name of the song when Yato uses Yukine to cut through the Pacification Ring to rescue Ebisu in episode 13 in Noragami Aragoto?

Tags: noragami

After Hiyori calls Yato from Yomi, he used Yukine to cut the "Pacification Ring" and they played a song that is so nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the flashback scene that starts around 4:59, this is "Reincarnation" ([*Noragami Aragoto* OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/56225), disc 1, track 8). [Here](https://clyp.it/yxlnpudo?token=61228a1f5f7746efb9c0de9a34e35ece) is an extract from the track (0:45-1:00).

Answer (score 0):

It's the 11th song on the soundtrack Footsteps. The portion we hear during that scene starts at minute 1:17 and crescendos around 2:00 when Yato uses Sekki.